# How to print to PDF without half toning? (Windows 2000)

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, windows-2000, proofing

I want to convert some documents from Micrografx Designer 4.1a for Windows 3.1 to PDF. So I set up Windows 2000 in a virtual machine and installed Adobe Acrobat Pro 7. This lets me print to PDF. However, even with image rescaling and compression turned to *off* in the PDF settings, half-tone patterns are created:

[image: Screenshot with VMware and PDF]

(original on the left, generated PDF on the right)

I also tried exporting using Bullzip PDF printer. However, that only generated garbage.

Comment: "Printing to pdf" means rasterising in most cases; you would need an intermediary which can deal with the original vector data. What export options do you have from your designer software?

Comment: It's bitmap data that gets rasterized, even if I disable image scaling and compression. I also selected "preserve original JPEGs", although the bitmaps may be in some other format. Micrografx Designer supports for export: AI, BMP, CGM, DRW, DXF, EPS, GEM, GIF, JPG, PCT, PCX, PLT, RTF, TGA, TIF, TXT, WMF, and WPG. With EPS/AI, depending on settings, either some of the text is missing or images, and I think certain text was always missing.

Comment: @feklee, JPEG is a (lossy, compressed) bitmap format, to get "no rasterization" you'd need to start with a vector format (one which describes curves, not points on the canvas).

Comment: @vonbrand If you look at the screen shot, you may understand that by rasterization I refer to half-toning, or the creation of a raster for printers. I simply want the original bitmap graphics to be included.